# Linux C++ Detect user shell (csh,bash,etc)

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I have a C++ application that needs to make shell specific commands using system calls.  Is there a way to detect which shell the user is running?  (Csh/Bash/etc).

Thanks

---

Elaborate

I'm trying to work with some code that forks off via `system` a `rsh` call that has a sequence of commands that are using `setenv` which doesnt work in bash.  I want to detect whether the system is `csh` or `bash` and rewrite the calls accordingly.

Comment: Maybe use popen to run `echo $SHELL`? or `echo $0`?

Comment: And which user? The one of the script or one of possibly many logged-in ones?

Comment: You check in `/etc/passwd`, eg: `cat /etc/passwd | grep user | cut -d: -f7`

Comment: @InnocentBystander And then? Is the current shell there? No

Comment: You need to run system commands or you need to run shell commands? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: @deviantfan, yes. http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd (last field)

Comment: @InnocentBystander OP (and I) asked about the *current* shell, not the login shell (OP wants to know because some commands should be executed)

Comment: @deviantfan, true, it does not tell you the *current* shell. but when was the last time you changed your shell mid-session?... :)

Comment: Jeef, as deviantfan asked, please elaborate a bit more on your question

Comment: @InnocentBystander The last time I bound a clean system to an IPA server that specified a shell for a particular user. How does checking `passwd` handle that?

Comment: @ssube, it doesn't. In that case use: `getent passwd <user> | cut -d: -f7`. You may need to use `head` or `tail` in case the user has records in both LDAP and passwd.

Comment: Don't `system` the (insecure) `rsh` command, but `fork` then `execve` it

Comment: You would like your system commands once. Try to specify the new shell in your rsh call. `rsh host [...] /bin/bash ls -l`

Comment: i have never heard of an 'etc' shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if this will be of any use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>     /* getenv */

int main ()
{
  char* Shell;
  Shell = getenv ("SHELL");
  if (Shell!=NULL)
  std::cout << Shell << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Will output something similar to

```
/bin/bash
```

Getenv returns a c-string with the environment variables value.

Link:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/

Comment: Compiles fine. Also comes null for path which is odd

Comment: @Jeef If you type env on the command line is one of the variables SHELL ?If not is there something that looks similar

Comment: No it should be there and getenv seems like the right answer... i'll have to look deeper into my specific build.  Maybe its time for a make clean.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work and will most probably work for bash only.

Answer (score 2):

Get the userid with [`geteuid`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/geteuid), get the user database entry for that ID [`getpwuid`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) containing the shell and *must not* be freed. So it breaks down to

```
getpwuid(geteuid())->pw_shell
```

Minimal working example:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s\n", getpwuid(geteuid())->pw_shell);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed with getting BASH_VERSION/ZSH_VERSION/... env vars as they are not exported to child processes; /etc/passwd gives login shell, thus the only way to get current shell I found is:

```
const char* get_process_name_by_pid(const int pid)
{
    char* name = (char*)calloc(256,sizeof(char));
    if(name){
        sprintf(name, "/proc/%d/cmdline",pid);
        FILE* f = fopen(name,"r");
        if(f){
            size_t size = fread(name, sizeof(char), 256, f);
            if(size>0){
                if('\n'==name[size-1])
                    name[size-1]='\0';
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
    }
    return name;
}

bool isZshParentShell() {
    pid_t parentPid=getppid();
    const char* cmdline=get_process_name_by_pid(parentPid);
    return cmdline && strstr(cmdline, "zsh");
}
```